Azure Data Flow flatten and parse key/value column for complex JSON
I'm trying to transform a key/value data into column using Azure synapse Data Flow. Basically this:
"scoreIndeces": {
"66": 0.2,
"67": 0.3,
"68": 0.4,
"70": 0.5,
"71": 0.6,
"73": 0.7,
"77": 0.8,
"78": 0.9,
"80": 1,
"81": 1.1,
"82": 1.2,
"83": 1.3,
"84": 1.4,
"85": 1.5,
"86": 1.6,
"87": 1.7,
"88": 1.8,
"89": 1.9
}

into this:



scoreIndecesKey
scoreIndecesValue




66
0.2


67
0.3



How can I resolve this problem?
I followed the steps provided in this question, but it does not match my use case.

are you getting any error?

@RakeshGovindula , Now I am new to this azure synapse .
Actually this document comes under another document and  I have used flatten to get tabular form at one level but for scoreIndeces I need both the values as key and value.
I am finding difficult to retrieve it.

You can use Unpivot transformation in the Dataflow to achieve your requirement.
After getting the required scoreIndeces object as a column, extract the inner keys as columns using select transformation Rule-based mapping. In the select transformation select Add mapping-> Rules-based mapping and give the scoreIndeces object as the hierarchy level as shown below. This will extract all the inner keys as columns and rows.

To unpivot, it needs a grouped column. So, use Derived column transformation and create a new column key and give any string value. Also, convert all column values to strings using Derived column Column pattern option. Click on Add and select Column pattern and give below expressions.

Then, use the Unpivot transformation with below configurations.
Ungroup by : key

Unpivot key - Unpivot column name - scoreIndecesKey and type - string

Unpivoted columns - Column name - scoreIndecesValue and type - string

It will give the output like below.

Here, convert your columns to required data types using another Derived column.
scoreIndecesKey - toInteger(scoreIndecesKey)
scoreIndecesValue - toDouble(scoreIndecesValue)


Now, it will convert the columns to required data type. Remove the extra key column using another select transformation and it will give the desired output.


Data looks like this
{
"timeFrames": [
{
"yearGroup": "Reception",
"term": "Summer",
"scoreIndeces": {
"66": 0.2,
"67": 0.3
}
},
{
"yearGroup": "Year 1",
"term": "Spring",
"scoreIndeces": {
"64": 0.6,
"65": 0.6
}
}
],
"tableType": 1,
"id": "f82",
"productId": "4b",
"product": "PUMA"
}

Yes, first get the scoreIndeces object as a column. Then you can use the above steps to get the required results.

But I need to get in this way
id ,productid,product,yeargroup,term,scoreIndeceskey,scoreIndecesvalues.
Will it satisfy my above requirement ?

No, as your primary ask is related to the scoreIndeces JSON keys and values, I have given the solution for this. I don't know whether it works for your total JSON as I haven't seen it. You can check it after extracting the scoreIndeces and let me know the result or error here. I will try from my end.

Yes, I am also working on it.
Thanks for your contribution. If you find any solution please let me know.

Hi Rakesh Govindula,
Thank you soo much.
It helped me a lot .
I have followed the same steps as you given while unpivoting .
I have made slight changes
Ungroupby - id,term,yeargroup,key
unpivot key-scoreIndecesKey
unpivot value-scoreIndecesValue
It worked for me .
But if I get explanation from you  how unpivot works it will be more helpful for me

Good to know that my answer benefitted you. The Unpivot transformation is used to change columns to rows so that the unnormalized data can be normalized. Here it ungroups the given columns data and creates that many rows in the target. Thats why I have given one value and used that for ungroup. Here, it ungroups the data based on the given column. And in the next tabs I have given the column name for the previous column names (keys) and another column name for the values. You can go through this doc to know more about it

One question is it a good practice to convert source data cosmos to destination dedicated azure sql server

I cannot comment on it as I am not into cosmos. You can raise a new ask on it with relevant details and your approaches so that the community might assist you.

One thing I noticed while unpivot I found that unpivoted key was applied to all the rows and because of that  null values generated so I have checked a option to avoid null and verified the data with my data randomly and it looked fine

Yeah, you can do that to avoid null values.
